# php echo only first 20 characters from a variable string

Tags: php, string, variables

I have situation, where I have to echo certain length for several variables at various locations.

I know in bash we can use echo ${variable:0:20} to achieve this, without rewriting or refining the variable.

for example in php I want to be able to do this.

```
$string1 = "I am looking for a way to only echo the first 20 characters from a string variable";
echo $string:0:20;
```

I know it is dead simple to redefine my variable in php like this and echo it.

```
$small = substr($big, 0, 20);
echo $small;
```

But I have to use the same variable at some many location and each location I have to echo different length, so it is not feasible to use the above method. Is there is something else I am missing that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I know in bash we can use echo ${variable:0:20} to achieve this, without rewriting or refining the variable.*

In PHP you can use `echo substr($variable, 0, 20);` also without rewriting or refining the variable.

For convenience (and easy modifications, e.g. adding `...` to all wrapped strings) you can wrap this in a small function:

```
function shorten($string, $maxLength) {
    return substr($string, 0, $maxLength);
}
```

and use it as

```
echo shorten("Some very very very very very long string", 20);
```

Or even include the `echo` in your function:

```
function output($string, $maxLength) {
    echo substr($string, 0, $maxLength);
}
```

and use it as

```
output("Some very very very very very long string", 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to build a `function` so you can spare some lines of code, I don't see any other improvements you can make besides that, something like:

```
function small($string)
{
    return substr($string, 0, 20);
}
```

Use it as:

```
print small("Some sentence longer than 20 chars");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything but the fact that you can just echo the returned value from `substr` itself. If you want to go really short, like if writing the second parameter from `substr` is too much, just wrap it in a new function.

```
function
ss($string, $size)
{
    return substr($string, 0, $size);
}

echo ss('long ... string', 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use this `echo substr($string, 0, $length);`

**For more u can use this :**

```
function output($string, $maxLen) {
    echo substr($string, 0, $maxLen); 
    if(strlen($string) > $maxLen) echo ' ...';
}
```